# Issue in comparing two Strings in Selenium

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver

I am comparing value of selected option in a drop-down with the value being picked from Excel sheet. Irrelevant to both these values being same or different, answer is always coming 'false'

Here is my HTML code of dropdown, from where i am picking the selected value

```
<select id="un_lvt_edu" name="type" style="background: none repeat scroll   
0% 0% transparent;">
<option selected="selected" value="school_edu">School Education </option>
<option value="other_edu">Others </option>
<option value="total_edu">Total Education </option>
</select>
```

The code i am using for comparing values:

```
System.out.println(new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*   
[@id='un_lvt_edu']"))).getFirstSelectedOption().getText().trim().   
equalsIgnoreCase(workSheet.getRow(counter).getCell(2).toString().
trim()));
```

Result I am getting:

Excel value: School Education, 
Dropdown value: Total Education, 
Result: false

Excel value: School Education, 
Dropdown value: School Education,
Result: false

Comment: Please check for any hidden character in your excel data. If you have copied the data and pasted it in excel i would recommend to manually enter data in excel

Comment: @VivekSingh I have manually entered the data. The length of String coming from Excel and Dropdown are of same length, so I assume both have same characters.

Comment: Using compareTo(), I got the answer as -128, even though both the values- from Dropdown and from Excel shows same value- 'School Education.' How should i deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

My excel file was giving different ASCII value for same phrase, for example white-space in 'School Education' has value of 32 in browser while its 160 in Excel. I copied the value from browser to Excel which made sure that ASCII values remains same and then everything is working fine.